# Как сместить div, если его проскроллили?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как можно реализовать смещение блока допустим на 50px вправо, если блок div проскроллили вправо?

```
<div id="education_heroes" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 name_section">
            <a class="text_name_section_heroes">Education heroes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-dots">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon1 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Pierre Simon</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon2 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Galileo Galiley</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon3 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Rafaello Sanzio</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon4 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Marie<br>Curie</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon5 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Isaac Newton</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 education_heroes_icon1 education_heroes_icon-all">
                <div class="text_heroes_name">Wonder Woman</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.owl-dots').owlCarousel({
            loop:false, //Зацикливаем слайдер
            margin:0, //Отступ от элемента справа в 50px
            nav:false, //Отключение навигации
            autoplay:false, //Автозапуск слайдера
            smartSpeed:300, //Время движения слайда
            autoplayTimeout:0, //Время смены слайда
            mouseDrag: true,
            touchDrag: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            responsive:{ //Адаптивность. Кол-во выводимых элементов при определенной ширине.
                0:{
                    margin: 70
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Речь про плавающие div'ы?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, на сайте используется owl carousel, и реализовано отображение половины картинки слева и справа. Справа скролл работает, а слева не скроллится т.е так и остается половина картинки. Нужно сместить этот блок.

Comment: тот кусок кода, что в вопросе ничего об этом не говорит. Нужен тот, что скажет.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, добавил